# 3D Libgdx Opengl: How to make a shadeless material?

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, libgdx, shader

I am trying to make a Shadeless material, by this I mean that is not affected by the environmental lighting.
What attribute should I put? or how do I achieve this?

My enviromental light is:

```
environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f));

environment.add(new DirectionalLight().set(1f,1f,0f, -1f, -0.8f, -0.2f));
```

Here is an image of the problem, you can see the enviromental light is affecting the plane:

[image: libgdx shadeless]

some thing like this I assume with the correct Attribute would be the answer?

```
instance.materials.get(0).set(new FloatAttribute(FloatAttribute.Shininess, 1));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps simply not including the environment in the rendering :

```
ModelBatch batch = new ModelBatch();
...
public void render() {

    batch.begin(camera);

    batch.render(instance);
    batch.render(otherInstance, environment);

    batch.end();

}
```